# Probabilities of a biology experiment

Tags: probability, biology

So I was having a biology experiment about Mendel's law, and we are tasked to put 15 pairs of different beads with 4 different colors A, B, C, D (30 x 4 = 120 beads in total) for 2 different experiments:

1. 30 beads (15 colored A and 15 colored B) into 2 jars (each jar has 30 by the way), and
2. 30 beads (15 colored A and 15 colored B) in jar 1, and jar 3, and 30 beads (15 colored C and 15 colored D) in jar 2 and jar 4.

*A is white, B is red, C is yellow, and D is green

Basically what we do is close our eyes and take a bead at random from each jar, until there are no beads left.

What are the probabilities for each experiment? (For example I would expect a red-red : red-white : white-white to be a 1 : 2 : 1, is it true)? Also numbers kinda doesn't matter here, the number is chosen to be 30 just because we need more sample data.

Comment: Just some nit-picking with English: I understand that there are 4 colours A,B,C,D and 15 beads  in each colour. But your first sentence  "4-coloured beads" means different: it means each bead is multi-coloured with 4 colours.    Same way after talking of colours A,B,C,D then you talk of red and white. Please  either specify names for all 4 colours or stick to A,B,C,D to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Alright thx for the fix